# Getx navigation not responding Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, flutter-getx

I have been working on this Getx library for the first time and i don't know why but the **initial screen** function is not working for some reason. It's not showing any bug in the stack trace so i guess it's gotta be something else. has anyone any idea? Debug shows no error or warnings.

here's the code

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:tutorial_two/screens/screen_home.dart';
import 'package:tutorial_two/screens/screen_login.dart';
import 'package:velocity_x/velocity_x.dart';

class AuthController extends GetxController {
  static AuthController instance =
      Get.find(); // auth controller instance; will be called in other widgets
  // user instance
  late Rx<User?> _user;
  // get user data like name, email, password etc
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance; // firebase auth instance

  @override
  void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
    _user = Rx<User?>(auth.currentUser); // getting current user
    _user.bindStream(
      auth.userChanges(),
    ); //notifies app about user login and logout

    ever(_user,
        _initialScreen); //this funnction will make sure user gets to correct screen
  }

  _initialScreen(User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      Get.offAll(() => const LoginScreen());
    } else {
      Get.offAll(() => const HomeScreen());
    }
  }

  Future<void> register(
      BuildContext context, String email, username, password) async {
    try {
      await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      //await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
      Future.delayed(
          const Duration(
            seconds: 1,
          ), () {
        VxToast.show(context,
            msg: "Registration Successful",
            bgColor: Colors.green.shade100,
            textColor: Colors.green.shade500,
            textSize: 14,
            position: VxToastPosition.center);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      VxToast.show(context,
          msg: "Error: $e",
          bgColor: Colors.red.shade100,
          textColor: Colors.red.shade500,
          textSize: 14,
          position: VxToastPosition.center);
    }
  }

  Future<void> login(BuildContext context, String email, password) async {
    try {
      await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      //await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
      Future.delayed(
          const Duration(
            seconds: 1,
          ), () {
        VxToast.show(context,
            msg: "Login Successful",
            bgColor: Colors.green.shade100,
            textColor: Colors.green.shade500,
            textSize: 14,
            position: VxToastPosition.center);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      VxToast.show(context,
          msg: "Error: $e",
          bgColor: Colors.red.shade100,
          textColor: Colors.red.shade500,
          textSize: 14,
          position: VxToastPosition.center);
    }
  }

  Future<void> logOut(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      await auth.signOut();
    } catch (e) {
      VxToast.show(context,
          msg: "Error: $e",
          bgColor: Colors.red.shade100,
          textColor: Colors.red.shade500,
          textSize: 14,
          position: VxToastPosition.center);
    }
  }
}
```

here's the main code

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:tutorial_two/screens/screen_home.dart';
import 'package:tutorial_two/screens/screen_login.dart';
import 'package:tutorial_two/screens/screen_signup.dart';
import 'package:tutorial_two/screens/screen_splash.dart';
import 'package:tutorial_two/utils/auth_controller.dart';
import 'package:tutorial_two/utils/routes.dart';
import 'package:tutorial_two/widgets/themes.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Firebase.initializeApp().then((value) {
    Get.put(AuthController());
  });
  runApp(const TutorialTwo());
}

class TutorialTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  const TutorialTwo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      theme: MyTheme.lightTheme(context),
      darkTheme: MyTheme.darkTheme(context),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const SplashScreen(),
      routes: {
        MyRoutes.homeRoute: (context) => const HomeScreen(),
        MyRoutes.loginRoute: (context) => const LoginScreen(),
        MyRoutes.signupRoute: (context) => const SignupScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `Get` navigation management, you must use `GetMaterialApp` instead of `MaterialApp`,

```
//Replace the following line
return MaterialApp(
//with this one
return GetMaterialApp(
```